# How can I edit package Laravel then submit on Packagist

Tags: php, laravel, package, packagist

I found on the Packagist an package which make save my time to create CRUD features using artisan console. But it do not fit me perfectly, I want to re-edit it and publish to Packagist for personal use only. I will put a copyright in Readme file. How can I do this ? [Here is the packages](https://github.com/kEpEx/laravel-crud-generator)

Comment: Fork it, submit it to packagist.org

Comment: You should just make a pull-request to their github repository, unless you change it too much to fit your needs. In this case, you shouldn't, but you can fork them on github and make your own changes.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will contact with the author to ask permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You are free to fork the package on github and perform your changes. After that you simply can register your modified package as "new" package on packagist and use it in your application! 
Maybe a good option is to speak to the maintainer of the original package if your changes would benefit the original package aswell and could be added into that package!

Comment: Thank you for your support. I will contact with the author to ask permissions.